# Query multiply values in one column.

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables

Table student

`student_id | name 
  211      | John
  786      | Mike
  890      | Michelle`

Table related_students

`student_id | related_student_id 
  211      | 786
  211      | 890
  890      | 211`

I want to output list of related_students_id of each student

`student_id | related_students
    211      | 786, 890
    890      | 211`

Is there anyway I could get this kind of output? Joining the tables would only result to

`student_id | related_students 
  211      | 786
  211      | 890 
  890      | 211`

And i need to have the list of all related_student_id per student.

Comment: you can get by group_concat

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT
    student_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(related_student_id ORDER BY related_student_id) AS related_students
FROM related_students
GROUP BY
    student_id;
```